# Не работает man gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, man

Не работает команда `man gcc` :

```
No manual entry for gcc
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация **не находится** в пакете `gcc`, она находится в **отдельном** пакете под названием `gcc-doc`.

[Альтернативный путь](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

[Источник](https://superuser.com/questions/400897/man-gcc-not-working)